# Google map not showing in tabs

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, tabs

Hi I have a problem with google map in tabs. It is not loading to full width. Here my code:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.2736, -76.8847),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and in html:

```
<div id="mapcanvas"></div>
```

the map looks like http://demo.mejorainfotech.com/swaranan/trans/Capture.PNG
and I am using bootstrap nav-tabs as tabs.
Thanks for yous assistance.

Comment: I seen this link before but it could not help me...i need some basic change ...